# SOAP message through HTTP in C sockets

Tags: c, sockets, http, soap, httprequest

I want to invoke webservice through C. I can't use any of the existing libs for the same. So I am opening the socket on Tomcat port 8080 (some app is running on Tomcat).

I am sending an HTTP POST request to tomcat via socket which includes SOAP message. I am able to invoke webservice but I can't receive data sent as SOAP. Here is a HTTP req with SOAP which I am sending via socket to Tomcat

```
    POST http://hostip.com:8080/APP/WebServiceName HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: "http://www.companyname.com/webservices"
User-Agent: Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1
Host: 192.168.50.151
Content-Length: length

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://www.company.com/webservices">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <web:DataRequest>
         <web:Scope>iOWNjuYroYC6HB</web:Scope>
         <web:Source>

            <web:ChildLine>
               <web:ID>RnUNjuYroYC6HB</web:ID>
               <web:Matrix>15</web:Matrix>
            </web:ChildLine>
         </web:Source>
         <web:UserVariables>           
            <web:Variable>
               <web:Key>Rule</web:Key>
               <web:Value>Working</web:Value>
            </web:Variable>
            <web:Variable>
               <web:Key>543</web:Key>
               <web:Value>96</web:Value>
            </web:Variable>
         </web:UserVariables>
      </web:DataRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I don't sure that i understand you exactly.
But ... If you send this sample message one-to-one, it's will be incorrect.
You need change the "length" text to the real length with *digits* in the "Content-Length: length" part. I think you change to the real length (in bytes, without header length), then maybe result will be better.

Comment: Hi,actually i am putting proper lenght there...i am count length of my message and then using snprintf i am inserting length...